# how to read hh, mm and ss in c++ in "hh:mm:ss" format

Tags: c++

How cin will read hh, mm and ss while the input format is **hh:mm:ss**
If I do

```
cin>>hh;
cout<<":";
cin>>mm;
```

then it will come in the next line which I don't want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: @Captain Yeah something like that. Refrained to hammer, since the question is lacking a [MCVE] in 1st place.

Comment: You'll have to write that parsing function yourself using more primitive io functions. It doesn't exist in the standard library.

Comment: @CaptainTrunky: How on Earth could that be a duplicate? I see no relation whatsoever between that question and this one, other than both being generally concerned with stream input functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all sure what the `cout << ":";` is supposed to have to do with anything here. It seems quite unrelated to reading anything.

To read `hh:mm:ss` you'd typically want to use `get_time`, something like this:

```
tm t;

std::cin >> std::get_time(&t, "%H:%M:%S");
```

So yes, contrary to popular belief there *is* something in the standard library specifically for this task (though the result ends up in a `struct tm` object, so if you want the results in separate variables, you'll need to copy them out of the `tm` yourself).